# help with octave '__spatial_filtering__' error in ordfiltn.m and imerode.m

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, octave

I was attempting to run this matlab code through octave from this site:

http://www.vision.huji.ac.il/SpectralMatting/

and got this error (after making the mex file using mkoctfile):

```
computing Laplacian matrix
error: `__spatial_filtering__' undefined near line 98 column 10
error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/packages/3.2/image-1.0.12/ordfiltn.m at line 98, column 8
error:   /usr/share/octave/packages/3.2/image-1.0.12/imerode.m at line 34, column 8
error:   /home/ct/imgproc/spectralMattingCode/getLaplacian1.m at line 20, column 9
error:   /home/ct/imgproc/spectralMattingCode/SpectralMatting.m at line 21, column 2
error:   runAll.m at line 18, column 26
```

Any recommendations on why this is occuring and how I can go about fixing it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The

```
__spatial_filtering__.oct
```

file must be in your octave path. So, for example, in cygwin, if you've installed the octave-forge package, and for some reason your octave paths aren't set up correctly, you would type (in octave)

```
addpath('/usr/lib/octave/packages/image-1.0.14/i686-pc-cygwin-api-v45+')
```

since

```
__spatial_filtering__.oct
```

is located here:

```
/usr/lib/octave/packages/image-1.0.14/i686-pc-cygwin-api-v45+/__spatial_filtering__.oct
```

Comment: I had another error 
`
error: API version api-v53 found in .oct file function '__spatial_filtering__'
       does not match the running Octave (API version api-v55)
       this can lead to incorrect results or other failures
       you can fix this problem by recompiling this .oct file
`